# How Do I Plot Static Markers with Uber's "react-map-gl" Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl

The documentation of the `react-map-gl` library is clear for DraggableMarkers, but it does not indicate if/how I can plot *static* markers.  I just want a simple map with a few map markers (fixed to a lat/lng position). Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Here is the link: https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl

Comment: What do you mean by static markers? If you have a dataset in mapbox studio that contains the markers, you could create a map style that contains the dataset and use the style in `react-map-gl`. Or are you looking to create a layer (e.g. with points) in your client?

Comment: @forrert I have a geoJson that contains multiple points (lat/lng). I want to plot them on the map (as a layer), but I don't want those points to be draggable. It doesn't seem like the documentation covers that though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to display a GeoJSON layer with `react-map-gl` I would recommend the following steps:

1. Use the [mapbox API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=cURL#retrieve-a-style) to download the style
2. Add your GeoJSON as a [source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-geojson) to the style
3. Add your custom layer styling to the style
4. Wrap your resulting style with [`Immutable.fromJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) and provide it to your `MapGL` component via the `style` prop.

If you built your app with `redux` and the GeoJSON points are part of your state, I would recommend to keep the points and the downloaded (original) style in the store separately. The final style can then be constructed as described in [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html).